Unable to show all array items in out put in swiftui
Code: here i am getting correct number in filteredModuel array but it showing only arrays last item in contentView why? where am i wrong? how to fix.
struct SearchView: View {
@State private var searchKeyword: String = ""
@State private var selectedTab: Int = 0
@State private var optionsArray = ["Module", "Student", "Staff"]

@StateObject var viewModelSidemenu = SideMenuViewModel()
@State private var filteredModuel: [AppMenu] = []

@State private var selectedIndex: Int? = 4
@State private var navigateModule: Bool = false
@State private var moduleId: String = ""

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.Neumorphic.main
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            headerView()
            tabView()
                .frame(height: 50)
                .background(Color.brandColor)
                .padding(.top, 20)
            contentView()
        }
    }
    
    .onAppear {
        viewModelSidemenu.fetchAppLayout { success in
            
            filterDataModuel()
        }
    }
}

private func filterDataModuel() {
    filteredModuel = []
    guard let menus = viewModelSidemenu.layout?.menus else { return }
    for menu in menus {
        var result = menu.childMenus?.filter { $0.menuTitle.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchKeyword) } ?? []
        if result.isEmpty, menu.menuTitle.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchKeyword) {
            result.append(menu)
        }
        filteredModuel.append(contentsOf: result)
    }
    print("final filter \(filteredModuel)")
}



private func filterDataStu() {
    filteredStudents = viewModel.students.filter { student in
        let lowercasedKeyword = searchKeyword.lowercased()
        return (student.name?.lowercased().contains(lowercasedKeyword) ?? false) ||
        (student.admissionNumber?.lowercased().contains(lowercasedKeyword) ?? false)
    }
}


@ViewBuilder func headerView() -> some View {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.clear)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                                .stroke(Color.appGreen2, lineWidth: 2)
                        )
                        .cornerRadius(30)
                    HStack {
                        
                        TextField("Search...", text: $searchKeyword)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                            .padding(.vertical, 8)
                            .onChange(of: searchKeyword) { newValue in
                                filterDataModuel()
                                filterDataStu()
                            }
                        
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 8, bottom: 0, trailing: 8))
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                }
                .frame(height: 60)
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.leading, 10)
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder func tabView() -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(0..<optionsArray.count, id: \.self) { i in
                        let data = optionsArray[i]
                        Button {
                            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3)) {
                                selectedTab = i
                                filterDataModuel()
                                filterDataStu()
                            }
                        } label: {
                            VStack {
                                Text(data)
                                    .font(.calibriBold(with: 16))
                                
                            }
                            .frame(width: (geometry.size.width / CGFloat(optionsArray.count)), height: 45)
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(.plain)
                    }
                }
                .frame(height: 45)
            }
            .frame(height: 50)
            .background(Color.clear)
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder func contentView() -> some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.fixed(screenWidth/2), spacing: 0), GridItem(.fixed(screenWidth/2), spacing: 0)], spacing: 0) {
                if selectedTab == 0 {
                    ForEach(filteredModuel) { module in
                        Button {
                            // Handle module selection
                            moduleId = module.title?.lowercased() ?? ""
                            navigateModule = true
                            print("selected moduel \(moduleId)")
                        } label: {
                            moduelView(moduel: module)
                        }
                        .frame(width: screenWidth/2, height: screenWidth/2)
                    }
                }
                else if selectedTab == 1 {
                    ForEach(filteredStudents) { student in
                        Button {
                            selectedStudent = student
                            gotoStudent = true
                        } label: {
                            profileViewStu(student: student)
                        }
                        .frame(width: screenWidth/2, height: screenWidth/2)
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    @ViewBuilder func moduelView(moduel: AppMenu) -> some View {
        VStack {
            let urlStr = moduel.icon ?? ""
            URLImageView(url: urlStr, placeholder: "NoProfilePic", width: 100, height: 100, renderingMode: .template)
                .foregroundStyle(.black)
                .padding()
            
            Text(moduel.title ?? " ")
                .font(.calibriBold(with: 16))
                .foregroundStyle(Color.hex1E1D0E)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder func profileViewStu(student: Student) -> some View {
        VStack {
            let urlStr = student.photo ?? ""
            URLImageView(url: urlStr, placeholder: "NoProfilePic", width: 100, height: 100)
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .padding(.bottom, 15)
            Text("\(student.name ?? " ") (\(student.studentClass ?? " "))")
                .font(.calibriBold(with: 15))
                .foregroundStyle(Color.hex1E1D0E)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        }
    }
}

o/p

final filter [e_Care.AppMenu(title: Optional("Staff Profile"), menuID: Optional(0), chMenuID: Optional(4), url: nil, icon: Optional("https://api-stavvprofile.svg"), slNo: Optional(0), childMenus: nil), e_Care.AppMenu(title: Optional("Staff Leave"), menuID: Optional(0), chMenuID: Optional(6), url: nil, icon: Optional("https://api-leave.svg"), slNo: Optional(0), childMenus: nil), e_Care.AppMenu(title: Optional("Staff Attendance"), menuID: Optional(0), chMenuID: Optional(62), url: nil, icon: Optional("https://api-ap-StaffAttendance.svg"), slNo: Optional(0), childMenus: nil)]


facing this issue from long.. for student filter able to show correct

Not part of this issue but I believe this is because of the incorrect conformance to Identifiable in one of your structures. In AppMenu change the id property to var id: Int { chMenuID ?? menuID ?? 0 }. Note that from what I see menuID doesn't need to be optional. Even if this doesn't fix the issue here you still need to apply my fix or all child menu objects will have an id of zero.

@JoakimDanielson, oh yeah. thank you sooooo much var id: Int { chMenuID ?? menuID ?? 0 } this is perfect

The problem is probably in the contentView view, where you're not iterating over filteredModuel to show all items. You're probably only showing the last element.
struct SearchView: View {
// ... other properties

var body: some View {
    // ... other views
    contentView() // This is the key change
}
// ...

var contentView: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(filteredModuel, id: \.id) { module in
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(module.title)
                        .font(.title3)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    if module.hasSubmenu {
                        Text(module.description)
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
}

// ... other functions
}


noo this is already in ScrollView > LazyVGrid... and with same code for student filter works perfect
